Create a JSON and put it as parameter to az deployment group create in Github Actions
I have quite strange behavior with deploying arm template.
I create a json like:
 tags=$( echo '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}' )

also, tried just:
 tags='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'

then I want to provide this as argument to my deployment command:
        az deployment group create --resource-group $gn \
        --name $dn \
        --template-file $armTemplatePath \
        --parameters $armTemplateParams \
        --parameters subscriptionId=$sub \
        --parameters name=$name \
        --parameters resourceGroupName=$gn \
        --parameters location=$loc \
        --parameters hostingPlanName=$hp \
        --parameters serverFarmResourceGroup=$sfrg \
        --parameters resourceTags=$tags \

but I constantly receive the error:
 Tags ***"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"***

apparently, the symbols { and } are getting replaced on ***. I know sometimes such logic can hide secrets in github actions, but not sure what's the deal here. How to provide tags in my case (I tried different ways including env variables which gets the same result)?
note: this is how tags are defined in template.json:
    "resourceTags": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {
        }
    }

and then in resource definition:
  ...
  "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
  ...


Did you try escaping the double quotes? tags=$( echo '{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\", \"key3\": \"value3\"}' )

@GuiFalourd, yes, same issue, the problem is with } and {

Generally the *** represents a secret. Do you have a secret set that may be using those brackets?

Otherwise, an option could also be to use a tags.json file and referred it like this: --parameters resourceTags=@tags.json in the command line.

Do you have a secret set that may be using those brackets? - no, nothing like this at all amd the only hidden information are symbols } / {

@GuiFalourd, in this case --parameters resourceTags=@tags.json , tag.json is a filename, right? what if it will be a path? @\path\tags.json?

Are you using the actions/checkout somewhere? If yes, this file could be at the repository root.

yeah, I use download-artifact and I know where the file is placed. I just not sure about supported format (@fileName) and didn't find any documentation about it

You should be able to achieve it like this:
--parameters resourceTags="$tags" 

Complete JSON string will be sent as a single token.
